# Microsoft Visual Studio Interface is not making sense to me

Tags: visual-studio

Apologies if this doesn't belong here. I tried Reddit, but got trolled. I'm just at a loss and am struggling to follow tutorials, etc because of it.

I'm coming from an exclusively Python background and have always used Pycharm. I'm now attempting to learn Java & the React fw and would like to use MS Visual, but am confused on why my interface is completely different from every other one I am seeing.

I realize this is a basic question, but I think if I can just figure it out, I'll be able to resolve a few other issues I'm having as well.

[This is what their interface looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgzcA.jpg)

[This is what mine looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi91z.jpg)

I've tried researching the issue but have not had any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the incorrect software. Your first screenshot is using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) which is a code editor (not an IDE) that is completely separate from the Visual Studio IDE.